# fill lists with another list with conditions

Tags: c#

I have a list:

```
List<string> letters = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
```

and I have another lists that contains another strings:

```
List<string> myList1 = { "f3", "g4", "h5" };
List<string> myList2 = { "z5", "w7", "q9" };
List<string> myList3 = { "k5", "n7" };
```

I want to fill myLists with `letters` list with conditions:
Every list can contain 5 elements in total and don't add a letter twice for the same list.

In the example above,

```
myList1 = { "f3", "g4", "h5", "a", "b"};
myList2 = { "z5", "w7", "q9", "c", "d"};
myList3 = { "k5", "n7", "e", "f", "d" };
```

regarding to `myList3`, `d` was added randomly (don't forget that I don't want to add "e" or "f" twice).

Please note that if I had this case:

```
List<string> myList1 = { "f3", "g4", "h5", "t3", "u6" };
List<string> myList2 = { "z5", "w7", "q9", "k9" };
List<string> myList3 = { "k5", "n7", "d3", "n6" };
```

The output is:

```
myList1 = { "f3", "g4", "h5", "t3", "u6" };
myList2 = { "z5", "w7", "q9", "k9", "a" };
myList3 = { "k5", "n7", "d3", "n6", "b" };
```

If it helps, myList1 has more/equal elements than `myList2` and `myList3` when it's declared.

I tried to do it, but I have lots of conditions that it's unreadable.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: So whats the actual question, i see you have home work (and that's totally fine) however which part are you stuck on. I.e there are multiple steps to this problem, which step are you up too, what have you researched so far. You (as a good programmer) have thought about this logically, so how have you attempted this, and why didn't it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lot of ways to approach it, would have been better had you shared your approach and we could help you with it. Anyways,following is one approach you could opt.

You could write an extension method called Fill.

```
public static class Extension
{
   public static IEnumerable<T> Circle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int startIndex)
  {
    return list.Skip(startIndex).Concat(list.Take(startIndex));
  }

  public static void Fill<T>(this List<T> source, List<T> reference, int maxCount,ref int index)
  {
    if(source.Count() >= maxCount) return;

    var difference = source.Count() - maxCount;
    var newReferenceList = reference.Circle(index);

    source.AddRange(newReferenceList.Where(x=>!source.Contains(x)).Take(maxCount- source.Count()));
    index+=Math.Abs(difference);

    if(index > maxCount) index = 0;
 }
}
```

And then in your client,

```
int index = 0;
myList1.Fill(letters,5,ref index);
myList2.Fill(letters,5,ref index);
myList3.Fill(letters,5,ref index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        letters = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
        myList1 = new List<string> { "f3", "g4", "h5" };
        myList2 = new List<string> { "z5", "w7", "q9" };
        myList3 = new List<string> { "k5", "n7" };

        FillLists(letters, new List<List<string>> { myList1, myList2, myList3 });
    }

    private void FillLists(List<string> listToFillWith, List<List<string>> allLists)
    {
        char lastItemInList = listToFillWith.Last()[0]; //We get the last item inside the listToFillWith list and with the [0] we convert this string to a char

        foreach (List<string> list in allLists) //We loop through each list inside allLists
        {
            while(list.Count != 5) //While either list 1, 2 or 3 does not have 5 items
            {
                if (listToFillWith.Count > 0) //Make sure our listToFillWith still has items to fill our list
                {
                    list.Add(listToFillWith[0]); //Add the first item from listToFillWith to our list
                    listToFillWith.Remove(listToFillWith[0]); //Remove the first item from listToFillWith so we don't add it again
                }
                else //If listToFillWith is empty
                {

                    char nextLetter;
                    //Here we check if the last item in the listToFillWith is a Z or z
                    if (lastItemInList == 'z')
                    {
                        nextLetter = 'a';
                    }
                    else if (lastItemInList == 'Z')
                    {
                        nextLetter = 'A';
                    }
                    else //If the last item in the listToFillWith is not a Z or z we get the last letter and go to the next letter in the alphabet
                    {
                        nextLetter = (char)(((int)lastItemInList) + 1);
                    }

                    list.Add(nextLetter.ToString()); //Add the next letter in the alphabet to the list
                }
            }
        }
    }
```